# AngularJS seems to ignore my bindings

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a dictionary of data to Angular, and it is being quite ornery about ignoring whatever I tell it to do.

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
   "Attributes" : [
      "Stamina": 1,
      "Strength": 2
   ],
   "Coefficients": [
      "Constitution": 0.5
   ]
}
```

Using a controller similar to this:

```
var controller = function($scope){
   var _this = $scope;
   _this.model ={ 
       Statistics : {} 
   }
  // (ajax to get list of data and populate "Statistics")
};
angular.module('app').controller(["UserController", "$scope"]);
```

And I am trying to bind it very simply:

```
<div ng-controller="UserController">
   {{ model.Statistics["Attributes"]["Stamina"] }}
</div>
```

Can anyone help me pinpoint why it refuses to display the number?

Comment: You don't need `model` in expression

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately that didn't fix it.

Comment: It is made even more frustrating by the fact that I get no errors.

Comment: It seems like you typed the code in question (there is a typo - should be `Statistics: {}`, not `=`). Please make sure that you paste the actual code... and some code about how you populate the object is also important

Comment: Try printing `Statistics` only

Comment: @Tushar, There is `.model` - why would you say `model` is not needed?

Comment: Trying to print `Statistics` only yields nothing. It is just blank. No error or anything.

Comment: Have you updated Statistics after http request completion

Comment: Yes, I have. I can also verify that the data is correct.

Comment: In addition to everything else, you probably want to define `Attributes` as an object, not an array, b/c you're binding to it as if it were an object.

Comment: That isn't an option. It is all coming in from a server, I can't control the shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never attaching your controller function or setting the model

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("UserController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
      "Statistics": {
        "Attributes": {
          "Stamina": 1,
          "Strength": 2
        },
        "Coefficients": {
          "Constitution": 0.5
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="UserController">
  {{ model.Statistics.Attributes.Stamina }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed this - but unfortunately it didn't make it work.

Comment: After trying everything here, I found out that I have to manually run `$scope.$apply` to make it work. Is there any workaround to that?

Comment: @Ciel, show more of your code - especially the one that obtains the data asynchronously. And please fix the obvious errors/typos in your code to avoid unnecessary answers

Comment: above example works now. @New Dev has the correct syntax (I accidently left the "UserController" inside the array). Also you have array braces instead of curly braces in your model, which is a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

You are registering your controller incorrectly. It should be:

```
.controller("UserController", controller);
```

or,

```
.controller("UserController", ["$scope", controller]);
```

with `controller` being the controller constructor function as you defined it.